# Expected Procedure Error from Function that Should Expect Boolean

Tags: scheme, racket, parentheses

So I am trying to write a function that iterates through a list of points and counts the number of points that are less than a certain distance from a given plane. My issue is that I am getting the "expected a procedure" error even though my function is written to receive a conditional. Specifically this error:

```lisp
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: #f
```

Below are the two functions. The error always points to the #t/#f that the checkDistEps returns.

plane is a list of 4 atoms, point is a list of 3 atoms (at the point when the error happens), and eps is a number

```lisp
(define checkDistEps
  (lambda (plane point eps)
    (if 
     (< (/ (abs(+ (* (car plane) (car point)) (* (cadr plane) (cadr point)) (* (caddr plane) (caddr point)) (cadddr plane)))
       (sqrt(+ (expt (car plane) 2) (expt (cadr plane) 2) (expt (caddr plane) 2)))) eps)
     (#t)
     (#f))))

(define iterateDist
  (lambda (plane points eps)
    (let iterate ((n 0))
      (cond
        ((list? (car points))
         (begin
           (iterateDist plane (car points) eps)
           (iterateDist plane (cdr points) eps)))
        ((null? points)
         (0))
        (else
         (cond
           ((checkDistEps plane points eps)
            (add1 n))
           (else (0))))))))
```

I tried replacing these lines (where the error comes from)

```lisp
((checkDistEps plane points eps)
```

With this

```lisp
((eq? (checkDistEps plane points eps) #t)
```

Among many other, similar changes. Nothing has helped. Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Don't put `#t` and `#f` inside `()`. `(#t)` is a procedure call, trying to call a procedure named `#t`

Comment: Just like `(add1 n)` calls the procedure named `add1`.

Comment: There's no need for `(if <something> #t #f)`. Since `<something>` already returns `#t` or `#f`, you can just return that.

Comment: You're using too many parentheses (`(0)` is not `{ return 0; }` but a procedure call); `iterate` is defined but never used (do you believe that it's like a while-loop?); and you're ignoring the value of `(iterateDist plane (car points) eps)`. Forget about other languages that you might be familiar with.

Comment: On a side note, `#t` and `#f` are booleans, `(if c t e)` is a conditional.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, I thought the error was because the line (checkDistEps plane points eps) was expecting a procedure but it was actually the (#t) that was expecting it and causing the error.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah, I just started with Scheme and am not used to parentheses being so important. The code is just bad, I was just adding anything to try to get it to work so that's why there's random lines and ignored values. I've completely redone it now. And yeah, they are booleans, my brain was completely fried when I wrote this. Have updated the title to make it more clear.

Comment: Is this homework? Are there any requirements you have to satisfy (allowed/ disallowed functions, using recursion for iterating...) or can you use anything?

Comment: @MartinPůda it was homework and we just weren't allowed to use ! functions like set! But I ended up just redo-ing it the whole thing since the iterateDist function was completely wrong.